# Sequence of weapons in Vishnu's hands

Tags: vishnu, puranas, symbolism, weapon

I have seen idols of Lord Vishnu having the Shankh, Chakra, Gada,Padma(Lotus) at different locations of 4 hands. Are there any logic,myth behind it ? Which position is true and original?

Comment: You can read here about weapon arrangements in hands of Lord Vishnu : http://www.iskcondesiretree.com/profiles/blogs/24-forms-of-vishnu